# If statements with SQL and returning string values

Tags: sql

I'm using SQL and I need to return one string if the value of a field is 5 and another string if the value of the field is 4. I have something like this right now:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value1=4 OR value1=5;
```

In PHP for example it might be like this (but I can't use PHP for my application):

```
if ($value1 == 4) {
 $value1 = 'free';
} elseif ($value1 == 5) {
 $value1 = 'not free';
} elseif...etc.
```

Anyone know how to accomplish what I want with SQL only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you would do something like:

```
select (case when value1 = 4 then 'free' else 'not free' end) as newval
from tablename
where value1 in (4, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that.

Comment: I edited my sql (see above) but it's returning no results when I add your code. Can you help me troubleshoot the sql?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask another question with the updated problem.

Comment: actually I figured it out on my own. Just changed the case statement to read as follows: CASE fdfp.field_price_tid WHEN  5 THEN 'free' WHEN 4 THEN 'see website' END AS Price